# kill not killing all processes on ubuntu16

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I used to use the following command line code to kill all processes

```
kill `ps -ef| grep -i selenium | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'`
```

but that does not work in ubuntu16

can someone pls help?

Answer (score 1):

From [kill man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill):

> If no signal is specified, the TERM signal is sent. The
>   TERM signal will kill processes which do not catch this
>   signal. For other processes, it may be necessary to use
>   the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be caught.

In other words, if a process register for catch a KILL signal but it never respond to it (is: by being stuck) it will *not* be killed.

To force close an unresponsive process you can use the `kill -9` command, which instruct the operating system to immediately kill the target process.

Answer (score -1):

alternatives:

- `pkill`,
- `killall`

or `killall -9` if you are not afraid of zombie